# Getting an error(cannot import name 'BertPreTrainedModel') while importing classification model from simpletransformers

Tags: keras, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

Getting the following error while  trying to import the classificationmodel from simpletransformers.

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-29f08e6c2d87> in <module>()
----> 1 from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel, ClassificationArgs

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/simpletransformers/classification/transformer_models/roberta_model.py in <module>()
      2 import torch.nn as nn
      3 from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss, MSELoss
----> 4 from transformers.modeling_roberta import (
      5     ROBERTA_PRETRAINED_MODEL_ARCHIVE_LIST,
      6     BertPreTrainedModel,

ImportError: cannot import name 'BertPreTrainedModel'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `from pytorch_pretrained_bert.modeling import BertPreTrainedModel`

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/446) github issue the problem was an old version of `simpletransformers`. To get the latest version do `pip install --upgrade simpletransformers`. Maybe even do this for the `transformers` package as well.

Comment: Seems that the latest version of transformers isn't working well with simpletransformers.So had to downgrade both of them to a previous one. !pip install transformers==3.1.0 ; !pip install simpletransformers==0.48.1. After downgrading it is working fine.